# Locking down Windows 7 and only allowing outbound calls on 80/443

Tags: windows

I need to harden a windows 7 PC running in a kiosk type device.

Basically the hardware on the PC only needs to make outbount HTTP requests and communicate with some peripherals over USB(COM ports).

Can someone provide an easy way to accomplish this quickly and effectively or point me to some resources with a complete list of the steps to take and ports to block

Comment: What do you mean by "outbound calls on 80/443"? TCP/IP connections aren't calls, and if you're saying that the computer needs to be able to make outbound HTTP connections, then they wouldn't be using ports 80 or 443. Those would be the ports the target web server is listening on, but the client would use a random port in the higher port ranges locally to make the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of the answers on the Security Stack Exchange question on [Attacking Kiosks](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4314/485).

Configuring your outbound firewall is a very small part of the story - to help dissuade attackers there are a much wider range of security controls you need to think about:

eg. will someone actually steal the hardware, can they plug in a USB or other device

Answer (score 2):

check this out [7 Steps to Harden Windows 7](http://www.winfrastructure.net/article.aspx?BlogEntry=Quick-steps-to-Windows-7-OS-hardening)
and also check the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the preconfigured security policy templates that come with windows 7.  The high security template is a great place to start configuring your group policies.  This will allow you to restrict not only unwanted traffic but also physical ports such as your USB and any oother physical connections your device may have.  Futher information can be found at the link below.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742512.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You could simply configure a firewall to block all ports except the ones you need open. It's really not that difficult. Remember to leave 80 and 443 outbound open.

Comment: LMGTFY is generally considered to be in bad taste here.